# Creating a specific 2D array of random Boolean values

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, boolean

I'm currently writing a program that will create a 2D matrix of Booleans given the size. I need to use a seed in a random object to create the true/false values that the grid will be made up of. The false values should be represented by - and the true values are represented by #.
I'm currently stuck on using the seed to make the true/false value grid and I'm not sure how to represent the true/false values with the specified characters.

This is what my current code is.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class Life {

public static void main(String [] args) {
    int rows = 6;
    int columns = 8;
    Random rand = new Random();
    rand.setSeed(7);
    boolean[][]matrix = new boolean[rows][columns];

    for (int row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++ ) {
        for (int col = 0; col < matrix[row].length; col++) {

            matrix[row][col] = rand.nextBoolean();

            System.out.print(matrix[row][col] + "\t");

        }
    }
}
}
```

My current results are as follows:

```
true    true    true    false   false   false   true    true    true    true    false   true    false   false   true    true    false   true    true    false   true    false   true    true    true    true    false   true    false   true    false   true    true    true    false   true    false   true    true    true    false   true    false   false   true    true    false   true
```

This is all in a straight line instead of a 6 x 8 grid.

What I would like it to say is something like this

```
- = - - = - = -
= - - = - = - -
- - = - - = - = 
- = - - = - = -
= - = - - = - -
- - - = = - - =
```

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to decide which character to print depending on the value in the array. This can be done with the ternary operator:

```
System.out.print((matrix[row][col] ? "=" : "-") + " "); // a space is fine, you don't need a tab.
```

Then, you need to print an extra line at the end of each iteration of the outer for loop, because the outer for loop is the one that prints rows.

Your loops should look like this:

```
for (int row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++ ) {
    for (int col = 0; col < matrix[row].length; col++) {

        matrix[row][col] = rand.nextBoolean();

        System.out.print((matrix[row][col] ? "=" : "-") + " ");

    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your edit. I forgot that I actually need a border of specifically default boolean values, so "-"'s. Do I need another nested for-loop for that, or would I change existing code?

Comment: I don’t understand what you mean by “a border of specifically default Boolean values”. Can you edit your question to show what you mean? @LukeCagno

Answer (score 0):

See @Sweeper's answer for a more simple solution.

You can also do this with streams:

```
String matrix = IntStream.range(rows)
    .mapToObj(i -> IntStream.range(columns)
        .mapToObj(j -> rand.nextBoolean())
        .map(b -> b? "=" : "-")
        .collect(Collectors.joining("\t")))
    .collect(Collectors.joining("\n")))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use an `enum` to represent the cell(s), you can create it with two possible values representing your "TRUE" and "FALSE" states, a function to map `boolean` to the correct value and override `toString()` for easier printing. Like,

```
static enum Cell {
    FALSE, TRUE;
    public static Cell fromBoolean(boolean a) {
        if (a) {
            return TRUE;
        }
        return FALSE;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        if (this == TRUE) {
            return "=";
        }
        return "-";
    }
}
```

Now your `main` method can convert the boolean from `matrix` into a `Cell` and `print` it like;

```
for (int row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < matrix[row].length; col++) {
        if (col != 0) {
            System.out.print(' ');
        }
        matrix[row][col] = rand.nextBoolean();
        System.out.print(Cell.fromBoolean(matrix[row][col]));
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```